# UIWebView async requests blocks scrolling

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uiwebview

I've been searching for something like this in SO and nothing came up. So i've decided to ask for the first time here.

I'm working on an iOS project. I have a UIWebView working fine with a NSURLRequest. But, when i load a URL with multiple asynchronous requests (i.e. wsj.com) like ads and Facebook likes stuff; the scroll interaction of the web view becomes laggy and unresponsive.

I've been debbugging and that happens when the delegate method shouldStartRequest is executed (several times)

First shoot: using threads. Didn't work.
Second shoot: playing with web view properties of interaction.
Third shoot: tried to stop the unnecessary calls (my business rules doesn't need them) didn't work. Even if i kill them, the laggy effect remains.

The curious thing about all this is that Safari renders and works fine with the same URL.

I'm looking for thoughts, does anybody has some clue of what's happening here?

Thanks!!

Comment: please post some of your code

Comment: Hi, there isn't a lot of code to show, just the request -> [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlTextField.text]]]; where urlTextfield.text value is @"http://wsj.com" the issue happens either if delegate methods are connected or not.

Comment: Have you tried on multiple networks? Have you tried on multiple devices? Is there any other code that has to do with the request?